# Geojson to shapefile convertion using shapefile library

Tags: python, geojson, shapefile

I know I can create a `shapefile` from a `geojson` if the `shapefile` only contains Polygons, but in case there is a `MultiPolygon` I get the following error:

> return [min(x), min(y), max(x), max(y)]
>
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'**

In `return self.__bbox(self._shapes)` method under `shapefile.py**`

Any ideas of how I can overcome this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
    import shapefile

    shape_file_writer = shapefile.Writer(SHAPE_FILE_TYPE)

    #example of field [field, "C", 200, 0]
    shape_file_writer.fields = self.__get_shape_file_fields() 
    for feature in geojson_data["features"]:
        if feature["geometry"]["type"] == "MultiPolygon":
            continue
        else:
            shape_file_writer.poly(parts=feature["geometry"]["coordinates"], shapeType=5)

        shape_file_writer.record(*feature["properties"].values())
```

Answer (score 0):

after some search I found that in a multi-polygon

[ 
polygon_0,
polygon_1,
.
.
]

only **polygon_0** is the actual polygon and the rest of polygons are **holes**.
In my case I didn't need the holes at all so I converted multi-polygons into polygons basically.