# Creating shapefile from GeoJSON with multipolygons?

Tags: python, geojson, shapefile

I am trying to do the same thing as this post:

[Geojson to shapefile convertion using shapefile library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50953209/geojson-to-shapefile-convertion-using-shapefile-library/51175950#51175950)

The user answered his own question, but I do not fully understand his answer. Can anyone please explain how he "converted multi-polygons into polygons"?

Answer (score 0):

A Multipolygon is a list of Polygons; just iterate over your Multis and store every item individually. Think of this like nested lists in Python: You need two loops to flatten a 2-level list, it’s the same for your Polygons.

Just don’t mix things up: A Polygon consists of an outer ring and inner rings (Linestrings) which themselves are lists of Points. Don’t dive too deep when iterating.

The linked answer is incorrect; might only be working in his certain case, or that person just mixed up the terminology. The major difference between Multipolygons and Polygons (besides their inner structure) is that a Multipolygon can have multiple outer rings.